# Undefined Macro in #if directive?

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
#if HELLO
   printf("%d\n",1);
#endif
}
```

In this code I am expecting `error` in the preprocessor stage because the maco `HELLO` is undefined. But it doesn't generate any error and simple ignore that `printf` statement. Why here `#if` directive act as `#ifdef` directive ?

Comment: Because that's what it does everywhere. Undefiend is considered a false value.

Comment: See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p3 *ff.*

Comment: Undefined macros evaluate to 0 — false — not an error.

Comment: They do not evaluate to 0 everywhere. The places where they do evaluate to 0 are quite specific.

Comment: @Ian, are you confusing _evaluate_ with _expand_?

Comment: (After an initial unproductive search for duplicates, I wrote an answer, and then I realized the number of the clause I quoted would be a useful search term for finding a duplicate.)

Comment: @TobySpeight It is replaced with 0, the controlling expression is evaluated.

Comment: You'll want `#ifndef HELLO #error halt and catch fire #endif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C 2018 6.10.1 4 says that each identifier in a `#if` directive that is not either defined as a macro or used with the `defined` operator is replaced with `0`:

> … After all replacements due to macro expansion and the `defined` unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number `0`, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token.

Regarding your statement:

> In this code I am expecting `error` in the preprocessor stage because the maco `HELLO` is undefined.

You should not expect that because no statement in the C standard says that should happen, nor does any reputable third-party documentation say it should happen. As you learn to program, be on guard about making assumptions about how things should behave. Learn to rely on written documentation rather than intuition.